# Hide/show columns on demand using Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hide, expand

I have a [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) website with an 8-column / 4-column setup.

On a large & medium screen, I want to be able to hide/show the 4-column on demand (with a button on the menu). When hidden, I want the 8-column to auto-expand to a full width (12-column) and vice-versa.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well... This is the best solution I could come up with. If anyone can think of a better one, please let me know.

```
       <p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function changeClass()
                {
                    var ElementCssClass = document.getElementById("main-column").className;

                    if ( ElementCssClass == "col-md-8 column" ) {
                        document.getElementById("main-column").className = "col-md-12 column";
                    }
                    else if ( ElementCssClass == "col-md-12 column" ) {
                        document.getElementById("main-column").className = "col-md-8 column";
                    }
                    ElementCssClass = "";
                    $('#side-column').toggle();
                }
            </script>
            <button class="button" onclick="changeClass();">Click to Show/Hide SideColumn</button>
        </p>
```